# How to print commandLine outputs with colors

Tags: gradle, build

I'm using Gradle to run a commandline task like so:

```
task checkAndBuild(type: Exec) {
    workingDir = "../frontend"
    commandLine "npm", "run", "flow"
}
```

When I run this program (npm run flow) from the terminal it prints the outputs with colors. Running the same program from Gradle also produces the same output, but without colors. How do I tell Gradle to print the output with colors?

Comment: ever hear anything on this, or figure out a solution?